# What is the fastest method to check if two conditions are True?

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators

For large arrays, what is the fastest way of checking whether multiple conditions are both True or both False? Does the choice of operator make a difference? Why or why not? Here is a dummy example:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ones((1000000,))
b = numpy.zeros((1000000,))

#c = (a == 1) * (b == 0)
#c = (a == 1) & (b == 0)
# other faster method of getting c?
```

notice edit...

Comment: Notice edit, just to be clear that the condition is not always the same for both arrays...

Comment: Does this optimization matter? Have you profiled your code and found this section to be too slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure this will matter for speed, but you can save memory by using in-place operations in this case.

Try something like:

```
c = a == 1
c &= b == 0 # (Or *=)
```

This should require one fewer temporary copies of the array and use less memory.

Comment: As far as I know, there shouldn't be a significant difference in any normal circumstance. My quick-and-dirty profiling seems to agree.

Answer (score 0):

You might take advantage of `Short-circuiting` of operators. And this Short-circuiting is different for different situations of different operators.

Comment: In the case of numpy arrays, this doesn't help. The result is another array of the same length. There's nothing to short-circuit.